# Is there a x64 (Windows) Driver for the ATI Radeon 7500 series cards?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Is there a x64 (Windows) Driver for the ATI Radeon 7500 series cards?

Running Server 2008 x64 on a system that's next to the display monitor for our shop. Instead of having an XP system sitting there just serving the monitor, I was hoping to pop a PCI Radeon 7500 into the system to serve the video.  The server is already running 2x http sites, so this wouldn't be a lag on it at...

Comment: Did you check with [AMD/ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)?  Or Windows Update? Or the MS Hardware [Compatibility Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductDetailsViewer?Type=Hardware&Name=AMD+RADEON+7500+64MB+PCI+Graphics+Card&ModelOrVersion=&Vendor=AMD&Locale=1033%2C2057%2C3081%2C4105%2C16393&LastSearchTerm=radeon%2B7500&BreadcrumbPath=radeon+7500&TempOsid=Windows+7)?

Comment: In the future, please don't regard Superuser as a "go find this for me" service. Search things before you post, as the answer to this question took me all of 10 seconds to Google and find.

Answer (score 1):

According to [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) (which, IMO, you should have looked at first), they only provide 32 bit drivers. This is probably because the card itself has a 32 bit hardware limitation, given that it is considered a legacy device.

I'm sure you're aware that you can use 32 bit drivers on a 64 bit system, right?